# Is it practical to have a Google Maps API key available for snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I was wondering, if we can import several libraries in HTML5 snippets like jQuery or AngularJS, would it be possible to be able to use APIs like Google Maps that require an API key, but without having to use our own key for obvious reasons?

What do you think?

Comment: Wouldn't we risk exceeding the quota and/or the rate limit? That's assuming it's even within the terms and conditions to use a key like that. I'd say it's probably going to cost more than it pays off.

Comment: For the free version of the API yes, but I'm pretty sure there is no limit providing Stack Overflow pays a fee.

Comment: If it's possible to lock the API key down to only getting run from stacksnippets.net (or whatever domain the snippet iframes run from), then sure. That way SO wouldn't be giving away free use of their key.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In Google Project Console, you can control which domain name are authorized to use the API key.